# how can I convert a char to a char* in c#?

Tags: c#

how can I convert a char to a char* in c#?

I'm initializeing a String object like this:

```
String test=new String('c');
```

and I'm getting this error:

`Argument '1': cannot convert from 'char' to 'char*'`

Comment: it seems that Unice does not know C# and the question is not terrible, but how many ways to init a string from a char (not very frequent need in .NET) we have find out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a bit of a strange way to initialize a string, if you know beforehand what you want to store in it.

You can simply use:

```
String test="c";
```

If you have a specific need to convert a char variable to a string, you can use the built in `ToString()` function:

```
String test = myCharVariable.ToString();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
unsafe
{
    char c = 'c';
    char *ch = &c;
}
```

Your example has a `String` and a compile error from using one of the String constructor overloads, so I'm guessing you really just want an array of chars, aka a `String` and maybe not a `char*`.

In which case:

```
char c = 'c';
string s = c.ToString(); // or...
string s1 = "" +c;
```

Also available:

```
unsafe
{
    char c = 'c';
    char* ch = &c;
    string s1 = new string(ch);
    string s2 = new string(c, 0);
}
```

Comment: this is the really answer to the question, but I believe the author does not really want converting `char` to `char*` :)

Comment: +1 because it answers the question without requiring that the OP justifies their need for this approach first.

Comment: Although, this is syntactically incorrect.  I think you mean `char* ch = &c;` *ch is used to change the value at the reference...

Comment: I think the code sample provided by the OP tells you this is _not_ an attempt to convert a char to a char*, but to "solve" the compile error...

Answer (score 7):

```
string myString1 = new string(new char[] {'a'});
string myString2 = 'a'.ToString();
string myString3 = "a";
string myString4 = new string('a', 1);
unsafe {
    char a = 'a';
    string myString5 = new string(&a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no overload of the public constructor for `String` that accepts a single `char` as a parameter. The closest match is

```
public String(char c, int count)
```

which creates a new `String` that repeats the `char c count` times. Thus, you could say

```
string s = new string('c', 1);
```

There are other options. There is a public constructor of `String` that accepts a `char[]` as a parameter:

```
public String(char[] value)
```

This will create a `String` that is initialized with the Unicode characters in `value`. Thus you could say

```
char c = 'c';
string s = new String(new char[] { c });
```

Another option is to say

```
char c = 'c'
string s = c.ToString();
```

But the most straightforward approach that most will expect to see is

```
string s = "c";
```

As for converting a `char` to a `char *` you can not safely do this. If you want to use the overload of the public constructor for `String` that accepts a `char *` as a parameter, you could do this:

```
unsafe {
    char c = 'c';
    char *p = &c;
    string s = new string(p);
}
```

Comment: Don't these "unsafe" versions assume that the byte following &c is a zero?

Answer (score 2):

Can't hurt to have yet another answer:

```
string test = string.Empty + 'c';
```

Comment: I don't find this to be a very elegant solution.. Why not use 'c'.ToString(), which is the shortest, most elegant and most logical solution? It's really interesting to see *how many* different ways to this are posted here..

Comment: I'm going to waste a vote on this just to get it back to 0. It's not wrong, it's just inelegant. Makes you wonder why the String constructor won't accept a character, though.

Comment: @John Ferguson: Thanks for voting this back up - I know it's not the most efficient, and is very inelegant, but the point of the answer was to show yet another variation. I thought downvotes were for *incorrect* answers, but seems people disagree.

Comment: I'm tempted to see how many downvotes I would get for answering:
`string test = string.format("{0}", 'c');`

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class has many constructors, if all you're after is to create a string containing one character, you can use the following:

```
String test = new String(new char[] { 'c' });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are hard coding it, is there a reason you cant just use:

```
String test = "c";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var test = 'c'.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a char in the String constructor, you should also give a count parameter to specify how many times that character should be added to the string:

```
String test=new String('c', 1);
```

See also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String test("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

String test = new String(new char[]{'c'});

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this conversion from your example is just change the type of quotes you are using from single quotes

```
String test = new String('c');
```

to double quotes and remove the constructor call:

```
String test = "c";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = 'R';
char *pc = &c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes (as in your question: `'c'`) means that you are creating a `char`. Using double quotes, e.g. `"c"`, means you creating a `string`. These are not interchangable types in c#.

A `char*`, as you might be aware, is how strings are represented in c++ to some extent, and c# supports some of the conventions of c++. This means that a `char*` can easily (for the programmer at least) be converted to a `string` in c#. Unfortunately a char is not inherently a char*, so the same cannot be done.